# How to return only rows that do not exist in another query (Access 2013) using NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't get this query to work. I'm trying to return every row that does NOT have a certain relationship in my tables.

```
group_id   |   group_name
--------------------------
    1            group1
    2            group2
    3            group3
    4            group4
    5            group5

relationship_id    |    from    |    to    |     type
-----------------------------------------------------
    1                    1            2       Subgroup
    3                    1            5       Subgroup
    4                    2            3       Subgroup
    5                    4            2       Subgroup
```

These tables create a hierarchial structure, where [from] is the parent ID and [to] is the child ID.

```
--group1
   --group2
       --group3
   -- group5
--group4
   --group2
```

I want to select every group that is not a child of another group. Basically, I want to select top-level only groups, that is, all groups without a parent. This is all groups with their ID not under [TO]

I started by querying to find all of the children. This query works as expected.

```
SELECT groups.*
FROM relationships INNER JOIN groups ON relationships.to = groups.ID
WHERE (((relationships.Type)="SubGroup"))
```

(The type is related to something else don't worry about that).

This correctly return the following:

```
group_id   |   group_name
--------------------------
    2            group2
    3            group3
    5            group5
```

So then, I figured I could use a `NOT EXISTS` to get the rows that I actually want.

```
SELECT groups.* FROM groups
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT groups.*
    FROM relationships INNER JOIN groups ON relationships.to = groups.ID
    WHERE (((relationships.Type)="SubGroup"))
  )
```

However, this returns no rows. Am I using `NOT EXISTS` wrong?

Comment: I have used `SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldname NOT IN(SELECT fieldname FROM table WHERE some criteria);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is groups whereas the groupID does not exist in the 'to' column in your relationships table.
Try this:

```
SELECT groups.* 
FROM groups
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
 SELECT 1
 FROM relationships 
 WHERE groups.group_id = relationships.to
)
```